# Visual Studio C# - How to let two (or more) checkboxes be checked, rest disabled?

Tags: c#, checkbox, foreach

I have the following code to let only 1 checkbox be selected in a groupbox, disabling others, and re-enabling when unchecked.

```
private void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox tmp = (CheckBox)sender;
    bool tmpStatus = tmp.Checked;
    foreach (CheckBox chk in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        if (tmp.Checked)
        {
            chk.Enabled = false;
            tmp.Enabled = tmpStatus;
        }
        else
        {
            chk.Enabled = true;
            tmp.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

How would I be able to make it so if two checkboxes in my groupbox are checked, make the others disabled, and re-enabled when at least one or more are unchecked. Would an int variable help? If so, how do I get that working, because I've been trying and I cannot get it to work.

Comment: You got a pretty good answer to this on the last question you asked.  Perhaps you should refine your coding skills more compared to asking more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Aydin's answer, but a little shorter:

```
    private void chk(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Make a list of all checkboxes.
        var checkboxes = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ToList();
        // Count how many are checked.
        int numberChecked = checkboxes.Where(x => x.Checked).ToList().Count;
        foreach (var cb in checkboxes)
        {
            cb.Enabled = numberChecked < 2 || cb.Checked;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This one works perfectly, for some reason, Aydin's solution was not working. Thank you so much, you and Aydin were extremely helpful.

Comment: I should have checked in the compiler but I couldn't be asked to create a test project :), glad it helped

Comment: @jgfoot There's some parts you can change to further improve the code :)... I didn't want to edit your post so I've put it up on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/AydinAdn/a9b6e54acf734cd22eaa), You're iterating through the code every time you call `ToList`, `Where` and `Count`... so you can trim off the fat in those areas

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the GroupBox(In the containers menu) ? It let's you do just the same... it's like a panel where radio buttons or checkboxes can be put, and they're all linked logically, so you can customize it to act like an MCQ type function or anything you want...
Here's a link that I hope helps you: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s4p12.html

Comment: it's not about _deselecting_  other checkbox(es), OP asking about paying with enable/disable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
var checkedControls = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                                   .Where(chk => chk.Checked == true);

var uncheckedControls = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                                     .Where(chk => chk.Checked == false);

if(checkedControls.Count() > 1)
{
    foreach (CheckBox chkBox in uncheckedControls) chkBox.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    foreach (CheckBox chkBox in uncheckedControls) chkBox.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Read the question, it is not about flipping enable/disable.

Comment: @HariPrasad Perhaps you should read my answer for a second time? `"How would I be able to make it so if two checkboxes in my groupbox are checked"`

Comment: True it is bit confusing, but if we read carefully `"How would I be able to make it so if two checkboxes in my groupbox are checked,"` this is one statement, followed to that OP is asking to disable all checkboxes when above case is satisfied.

Comment: @HariPrasad That is precisely what's happening... if 2 checkbox controls are checked, iterate through the unchecked controls and disable them... otherwise, enable them. He doesn't say disable all of them, only the ones which are not checked. If you read his code you'll see that he is first disabling all and then re-enabling the checked one

Comment: It does, title says _"How to let two (or more) checkboxes be checked, rest disabled?"_ :-)

Comment: @HariPrasad and the **rest *disabled***, meaning the remainder disabled